# Optimal bidding price for AWS EC2 spot block instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I need to attach a fixed number of spot block instances as core nodes to the EMR cluster at my job. The reason we're going with spot block instances is because our Spark jobs are pretty much deterministic in terms of execution time. I'm using the boto3 EMR client apis for spawning and killing EMRs. The only unknown part for me is how the bidding happens for spot blocks. AWS docs have a price chart [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/) for those instance types, but I can't find any information or apis for the accessing the bidding prices, similar to the ones present for normal spot instances.

The end goal is to find out the optimal bidding price, but I don't have any info rather than the static price chart. For the time being, I've set the bidding price to be 70% of the on-demand price using `BidPriceAsPercentageOfOnDemandPrice`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any data feeds for Spot Blocks. I suspect they are heavily dependent upon the current workloads and probably aren't used as much as normal Spot instances. The price would also vary based upon duration.

Please note that, **at the end of a Spot Block period, the instances are terminated**.

An alternative is to **use normal Spot instances, but include a mix of instance types** to reduce the likelihood of losing all of them.

These days, Spot instance can be terminated if capacity is reduced, even if the Spot price doesn't increase. This has resulted in a much smoother Spot price, but there is no guarantee of spot capacity even at the current Spot price.

Since Spot Blocks are more expensive than normal Spot instances, I'd suggest simply going for normal Spot on a couple of different instance types.

Comment: Thank you. Actually for dev environment, I think we'll go with spot instances. We can over-provision to guard against failure. For production, spot-blocks seems to be a better choice, as we need less volatility. What's your thought on that?

Comment: Using multiple instance types with Spot will give you pretty much the same availability as Spot Blocks. It would be rare to lose everything. I've seen some very big companies use Spot that way. Best thing is to experiment and see what works well for you!